# MySQL B-TREE index slows down "WHERE constant BETWEEN columnA AND columnB" query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table, about 3.6 million records. This table has 2 INT columns representing IPv4 "ranges" (from and to)

Without any index a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE INET_ATON("an ip address") BETWEEN fromi AND toi;
```

returns (5 rows) in about 4 seconds.

After adding an index on fromi and toi (`ADD INDEX foo USING BTREE (fromi ASC, toi ASC)`)

repeating the same query takes A LOT longer (I actually don't know how much because I aborted after 6 minutes).

I'd like to know why.

As far as I know there is no detailed "explain plan" in mysql. These are the results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

### Without index:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM tablename 
                 WHERE INET_ATON("an ip address") BETWEEN fromi AND toi;

select_type: SIMPLE
table: tablename
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 3634094
filtered: 100.00
Extra: Using where
#takes 4 seconds to query
```

### With index:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM tablename 
                 WHERE INET_ATON("an ip address") BETWEEN fromi AND toi;

select_type: SIMPLE
table: tablename
type: ALL
possible_keys: foo
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 3634094
filtered: 50.00
Extra: Using where
#takes really long to query

####################################################

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM tablename FORCE INDEX(foo) 
                 WHERE INET_ATON("an ip address") BETWEEN fromi AND toi;

select_type: SIMPLE
table: tablename
type: ALL
possible_keys: foo
key: foo
key_len: 5
ref: NULL
rows: 1817047
filtered: 100.00
Extra: Using where
#also takes really long to query
```

The strange thing is that the index slows down the query only by being there, mysql doesn't even use it (key: NULL).

Comment: EXPLAIN PLAN will answer it for you.  Look for TABLE SCAN.

Comment: ... in addition to @duffymo suggestion -- could you edit your question with the result of `EXPLAIN PLAN` in _both_ cases?

Comment: Yes, before & after should make it clear to all.

Comment: @duffymo that would be `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` in MySQL